# Error 404 después de instalar phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, ubuntu

He instalado el phpmyadmin en ubuntu pero me aparece que la página no existe cuando intento entrar a `http://localhost/phpmyadmin`

[image: phpmyadmin pagina no encontrada]

Estos son los comandos que uso para instalar phpmyadmin.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin php-mbstring php-gettext
```

Comment: Revisa tu pregunta, por favor. Los mensajes no indican ningún error. 1) los paquetes indicados __ya están instalados__; 2) el comando `autoremove`  elimina versiones obsoletas de paquetes actualizados. No está claro que es lo que _sigue saliendo_.

Comment: me sigue saliendo el mismo mensaje

Comment: ¿Qué mensaje? Eso es lo que no está claro. ¿Qué haces y qué sigue saliendo? Por ejemplo, si continuas intentando instalar `phpmyadmin`, evidentemente seguirás viendo que ya está instalado. Y si no ejecutas `sudo apt autoremove` seguirás viendo que hay paquetes que se pueden remover. __Aclara tu pregunta__, por favor.

Comment: Tienes que editar el título de pregunta, a "Error 404 después de instalar phpmyadmin".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas volver a configurar el `phpmyadmin`, lo más probable es que cuando instalaste no seleccionaste `apache`, por lo que la configuración automáticamente no se hizo.

Ejecuta:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin
```

Cuando aparezca esta interfaz, selecciona `apache` usando la tecla <kbd>SPACE</kbd>
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias Amigo me ayudo tu respuesta.